# How to get the same size for all the characters in an equation?

Tags: equations, mathtools, amssymb

I need to have the same size for all characters inside an equation. I did some research and i found a solution using align* instead of equation but in my case it doesn't work, I need to use equation.

[image: My code]

For example here when i use `\frac{}{}`, `\lambda` is smaller than the `\lambda` outside `\frac{}{}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:one}
\begin{split}
\textbf{X}^{-1} & = \left(\left(\begin{array}{ccc} {\underline{b}_{1}} & {\cdots} & {\underline{b}_{N}} \end{array}\right)\cdot \left(\begin{array}{ccc} {\lambda _{1}} & {\cdots} & {0} \\ {\vdots} & {\ddots} & {\vdots} \\ {0} & {\cdots} & {\lambda _{N}} \end{array}\right)\cdot \left(\begin{array}{ccc} {\underline{b}_{1}} & {\cdots} & {\underline{b}_{N}} \end{array}\right)^{-1} \right)^{-1}  \\

& = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} {\underline{b}_{1}} & {\cdots} & {\underline{b}_{N}} \end{array}\right)\cdot \left(\begin{array}{ccc} {\lambda _{1}} & {\cdots} & {0} \\ {\vdots} & {\ddots} & {\vdots} \\ {0} & {\cdots} & {\lambda _{N}} \end{array}\right)^{-1}\cdot \left(\begin{array}{ccc} {\underline{b}_{1}} & {\cdots} & {\underline{b}_{N}} \end{array}\right)^{-1}\\

& = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} {\underline{b}_{1}} & {\cdots} & {\underline{b}_{N}} \end{array}\right)\cdot \left(\begin{array}{ccc} {\frac{1}{\lambda _{1}}} & {\cdots} & {0} \\ {\vdots} & {\ddots} & {\vdots} \\ {0} & {\cdots} & {\frac{1}{\lambda _{N}}} \end{array}\right)^{-1}\cdot \left(\begin{array}{ccc} {\underline{b}_{1}} & {\cdots} & {\underline{b}_{N}} \end{array}\right)^{-1}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to obtain the same size for the whole equation (like below)? [image: What I need]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: Do please replace `\textbf{X}` with `\mathbf{X}`.

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Why do you encase the contents of each and every cell, in all `array` environments, in a pair of curly braces?

Comment: I used Grindeq and I got the equation more or less like this with the conversion Honestly, I didn't try to delete it because the equation was too long and I have thousands of equations to write

Comment: The main downside to all those needless pairs of curly braces is that it makes for an awful amount of code clutter. I'm not familiar with `Grindeq`, but whoever decided it would be a good idea to encase the contents of each and every cell in curly braces should reexamine why they did so -- and then, hopefully, decide to help contribute to less code clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two solutions:

- Replace `\frac` with `\dfrac` (see the third row in the screenshot below); or
- Employ inline-fraction notation instead of `\frac` (see the fourth row).

For the use case at hand, I'd prefer the inline-fraction solution since it avoids creating a needlessly tall matrix expression. That, or just keep using `\frac`: I doubt that your readers will experience any problems at all deciphering what the fraction terms denote.

I would also employ `pmatrix` environments instead of `\left(\begin{array}{ccc} ... \end{array}\right)`, replace some of the `^{-1}` terms with `'` (transpose), not employ the `\cdot` crutches, create a shorthand macro to abbreviate the many instances of `\underline{b}` and, most of all, *not* encase the contents of each and every cell in curly braces.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'split' and 'pmatrix' environments
\newcommand\ub{\underline{b}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:one}
\begin{split}
\mathbf{X}^{-1} 
&= \left(
\begin{pmatrix} 
    \ub_{1} & \cdots & \ub_{N} 
\end{pmatrix}
%\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix} 
    \lambda_{1} & \cdots & 0 \\ 
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
    0 & \cdots & \lambda_{N} 
\end{pmatrix}
%\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix} 
    \ub_{1} & \cdots & \ub_{N} 
\end{pmatrix}' 
\right)^{\!\!-1}  \\ % end of row 1
&= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
    \ub_{1} & \cdots & \ub_{N} 
\end{pmatrix}
%\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix} 
    \lambda_{1} & \cdots & 0 \\ 
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
    0 & \cdots & \lambda_{N} 
\end{pmatrix}^{\!\!-1}
%\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix} 
    \ub_{1} & \cdots & \ub_{N} 
\end{pmatrix}'\\ % end of row 2
&= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
    \ub_{1} & \cdots & \ub_{N} 
\end{pmatrix}
%\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix} 
    \dfrac{1}{\lambda_{1}} & \cdots & 0 \\ 
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 
    \cdots & \dfrac{1^{\mathstrut}}{\lambda_{N}} 
\end{pmatrix}^{\!\!-1}
%\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix} 
    \ub_{1} & \cdots & \ub_{N} 
\end{pmatrix}'\\ % end of row 3
&= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
    \ub_{1} & \cdots & \ub_{N} 
\end{pmatrix}
%\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix} 
    1/\lambda_{1} & \cdots & 0 \\ 
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 
    \cdots & 1/\lambda_{N} 
\end{pmatrix}^{\!\!-1}
%\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix} 
    \ub_{1} & \cdots & \ub_{N} 
\end{pmatrix}'
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful.. Now i need to change every equation i wrote

Comment: can i use something like ```\dfrac ``` for ```\sum``` ? i also need the same size with the limits,sum etc..

Comment: @HajerHraiechSakly - To generate the "large" summation symbol, I suggest you replace `\sum` with `\displaystyle\sum`, replace `\int` with `\displaystyle\int`, etc.